# c# override type comparison "is"?

Tags: c#, types, comparison

I'm trying to do something here and I may not be doing it right...

I have a base class "Damage", and a derived class "Melee : Damage", and another derived class "Ranged : Damage".

Then I have a "Unit" class, and a derived class "Warrior : Unit", and another derived class "archer : Unit".

So the unit class could be either a warrior which would be melee, or an archer which would be ranged.

So in my Unit class, I define a variable of type "Public Damage dmg".

Then in the constructor for Warrior, I set the "this.dmg = new Melee(dmg_amount);"
and in the constructor for archer, I set the "this.dmg = new Ranged(dmg_amount);"

Now I start passing around this unit.dmg variable throughout my code, and in some places I no longer really know that it's an archer or a warrior anymore, I just know the damage. So what I'm trying to do is check the damage type, via some code such as:

```
if (unit.dmg is Melee) {}
```

However, it tells me that "the given expression is never the provided ('Melee') type".

and I can understand why: I declared this.dmg to be of type "Damage". I guess I was hoping that when I set it to = new Melee() then it would forever remember that it is Melee damage, without further ado.

What is the easiest way to know that the Damage is Melee?

Comment: It should work...?! Could you show your complete class?

Comment: you should really just show all your code here

Comment: As per the code you have shown, your `this.dmg` has an instance of  `Melee`. `Melee` is derived from `Damage`. Which means `Melee` can have attributes\methods that are not in `Damage`. So `Damage` will never be `Melee`. But `Melee` will be `Damage` as `Melee` has everything `Damage` has.

Comment: This should definately work. The only problem I can think of, is, that maybe you have classes in other namespaces that have the same names as the ones you are working with, and then mixing them up.

Comment: @ThomasHilbert How will it work? Can you explain it?

Comment: .NET keeps track of the objects' types. The `is` operator will check whether the type of the investigated object is of given type, or of a type derived from given type.
So you can assign `object s = "test";` and then check if `s is string` and this will return true.

Comment: @ThomasHilbert `string` and `object` may not be an ideal example. But theoretically that's correct.

Comment: string derives from object, so this is quite the same case as the one in question, and it's the most basic types to demonstrate it on :-) Well, string is a ValueType, but the behaviour is the same in all relevant aspects.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments guys. When I saw the +1's that it should work, I looked again and found my problem. I had tried to test it with this line of code:

```
Debug.Write("Does this.dmg == Melee?" + this.dmg is Melee));
```

Which of course gave the error, because I forgot the brackets. I corrected it to:

```
Debug.Write("Does this.dmg == Melee?" + (this.dmg is Melee)));
```

and the problem is gone. I also took the time to test it various ways to make sure, and definitely this works. If I set it to this.dmg = Ranged(), then it no longer is "true" that it is Melee, and vise versa.